# appendChild not working with window.open in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, window.open, appendchild

I have a page with an svg tag. The page has a button called "Preview" which on clicking should  open a new window with the image (svg).

Below is a piece of code which works in Chrome/Firefox but not in IE (I'm using IE 9- IE9 standards mode)

```
var w = window.open();
var svg = $('#chart');              
var svgPrint = svg.cloneNode(true);
svgPrint.setAttribute('xmlns','http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
w.document.body.appendChild(svgPrint);
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose `about:blank` is run in Quirks mode, which doesn't support `svg`.

Comment: @Teemu It is being run in IE9 standards mode...

Comment: Yes, your main page is, but the `window` you open is more likely to run in Quirks mode, since it doesn't have a doctype declaration... Just test it by opening a real document in it.

Comment: @Teemu The above code doesn't work for other html elements also.. :( I tried opening new window with a html div which contains just a Text. Even that doesn't work.. I get a blank page.

Comment: Weird, IE throws SCRIPT5022 error (`Exception thrown and not caught`). But this code has nothing to do with `try..catch` ?! Also loading a real page to a newly opened window doesn't remove this error. Setting `w.document.body.innerHTML = '...'` seems to work. When enclosing `appendChild()` within `try..catch`, the error message is `HierarchyRequestError`, which means, that "The node cannot be inserted at the requested location." This smells a big bug in IE...

Comment: @ria look on my answer please...

Answer (score 14):

IE will block appending any element created in a different window context from the window context that the element is being appending to.

```
var childWindow = window.open('somepage.html');

//will throw the exception in IE
childWindow.document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));

//will not throw exception in IE
childWindow.document.body.appendChild(childWindow.document.createElement('div'));
```

Comment: I tried this.. but I'm getting this error: DOM Exception: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR (3)

Comment: Also where you have this error (sentence or part of code please)

Comment: Thanks guys! Creating the nodes in the same context I'm appending to solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

After dealing with the same issue, this is an excerpt of the solution that worked in my case for IE, avoiding the SCRIPT5022 error. Thanks to help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23098038/1532274).

```
var myWindow = window.open('about:blank', 'loading...', '');
var myWindowDoc = myWindow.document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html', null);
var myWindowBody = myWindow.document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'body');

myWindow.document.open().write('<html><head></head><body><div id="targetDiv"></div></body></html>');
myWindow.document.close();

try {
    myWindow.document.getElementById('targetDiv').appendChild(HTMLpayload.cloneNode(true)); 
} catch (e){
    if (HTMLpayload.outerHTML) {
        myWindow.document.getElementById('targetDiv').innerHTML = HTMLpayload.outerHTML;
    } else {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```