# Bug - IE 11 "Object doesn't support property or method appendChild" on Element node

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, bookmarklet

Kind of awkward. I have tried a simple script in Google Chrome, Moz FF, Opera, and it works like a charm there, and normally should as well in IE, but somehow IE tells me

> Object doesn't support property or method 'appendChild'

Strangely, my code is only this:

```
var close = document.createElement('button'); 
close.type = 'button';      
close.appendChild(document.createTextNode('CLOSE'));
```

I did have to turn off security settings in IE to enable the script to run because it is inside a bookmarklet (so dragged on the page). I found this post: [appendChild not working with window.open in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017682/appendchild-not-working-with-window-open-in-ie), and it says IE blocks appension in different window contexts. But in my case, how should I then append it 'in' the window?

Comment: does it work by itself without having to run it inside a bookmarklet?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a bookmarklet using almost the same code and it worked for me using IE11

```
javascript:(function(){ 
    var close = document.createElement('button');
    close.type = 'button'; 
    close.appendChild(document.createTextNode('CLOSE'));
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(close);
  })();
```